# Prove that every component of $E$ is unbounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a nonconstant entire function. Define $E=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : ｜f(z)｜>1\}$. Prove that every component of $E$ is unbounded. My attempt is that if $F$ is a component of $E$, then the continuity of $f$ shows that $|f(z)| \ge 1$ on $\partial F$. Assume $|f(z_0)|>1$ for some $z_0 \in \partial F$. Then I can show that $|f(z)|>1$ for all $z \in D(z_0,\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$. Thus $D(z_0,\delta) \subseteq E$ and it is impossible because $z_0 \in \partial F$. Therefore, we have $|f(z)|=1$ on $\partial F$. However, I stop at this point and I can't do anything. Please help!

Comment: By $f(z)>1$ you mean $f(z)\in\mathbb{R}\wedge f(z)>1$? Or did you mean $|f(z)|\ge 1$?

Comment: @Caffeine, you are right, it is $|f(z)|>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there exists a bounded component $F$ of $E=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |f(z)|> 1\}$. Then $|f(z)|=1$ on $\partial F$, as you already figured out. Because of the maximum modulus principle, $|f|$ attains its maximum on the compact set $\overline F$ only at points on the boundary. It follows that $|f(z)| \le 1$ in $F$, which is a contradiction.